# JWT for SSO (as used by ZenDesk)

Tags: single-sign-on, jwt

My experience with token-based authentication systems has always involved a token-exchange system. The application in which we want to authenticate the user receives a token (via request), and then securely transmits this token to the authenticating system's token exchange service, which validates the token and returns user information to the application.

I've recently come across ZenDesk's implementation of SSO, which uses JWT but no token exchange/validation step.

https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203663816-Setting-up-single-sign-on-with-JWT-JSON-Web-Token-

Example PHP implementation here: https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_jwt_sso_examples/blob/master/php_jwt.php

Basically, encoded user information is passed through a URL along with an HMAC to sign the request. The ZenDesk end will decode, validate the HMAC is valid (using a shared key), and immediately authenticate the user based on the request's user information. There is no callback to the system that generated the token to ensure it is valid.

My question is: If someone were to capture the request, and they decoded it to obtain the user information and the HMAC, couldn't they just send this up to a server farm to start iterating over secret keys until they figure out what it is (ie: making the HMACs match)? And then once you have the key, you could authenticate to ZenDesk as the CEO and make ridiculous requests?

Hopefully I'm missing something, as this approach to SSO is the simplest I've ever seen.

Answer (score 5):

You are exactly right.  The thing that you are missing is that - assuming the keyed hash used for the HMAC is secure and that the *key is strongly random and long enough* - it will be infeasible to brute force the key.